# Show a Certain Part of the Page

Tags: jquery

I would like to show a part of a website with jQuery .

for example, in this [link](http://imuzer.com/demo/index.php/our-works?view=project&id=2:pouya-sanat-2), I would like to show just `span4` class.

what is my wrong ?

```
$("body").load("http://imuzer.com/demo/index.php/our-works?view=project&id=2:pouya-sanat-2 div.span4");
```

Comment: In which site you are using above code? I am sure its an CORS issue.

Comment: I have not any output : http://jsfiddle.net/kg67ew0w/

Comment: You will get the error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://imuzer.com/demo/index.php/our-works?view=project&id=2:pouya-sanat-2. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`  See console error http://jsfiddle.net/qeyeshxw/

Answer (score 0):

Change the class name with ID.
So your code will be:
    $("body").load("http://imuzer.com/demo/index.php/our-works?view=project&id=2:pouya-sanat-2 #span4");